# Подскажите замену иностранным словам

Tags: значение-слов

Точное определение понятия "наука" это - систематизация системы.
Систематизация системы - это: 1) упорядочивание знания (есть система и её упорядочивают); 2) есть система для работы с некой другой системой (когда у некой системы имеются методы и способы упорядочивать что-либо).

Упорядочивание знания может быть: 1) непосредственным (точным (точные науки)); 2) отвлечённым (знание выявляется посредством чего-либо).
Есть система для работы с некой другой системой: 1) промышленность (промышленные науки); 2) создана система со знаками (числами) и она помогает в расчетах (обусловленная наука (математика, физика)).

Не могу справиться с заменой иностранных слов "систематизация" и "система" на русские слова. Хочу подобрать определение понятия "наука" из двух русских слов. Может, подскажете что-нибудь? Нужно, чтобы русское словосочетание вбирало в себя оба пункта определения: 1) упорядочивание знания; 2) есть система для работы с некой другой системой.

(в словари синонимов заглядывал)

Comment: "Систематизация системы" — это не "точное определение понятия наука", а неудачная попытка скаламбурить.

Comment: Однако именно этот 'каламбур' несёт в себе понимание. В русском языке при определении головного понятия вырисовываются деления этого понятия на другие понятия (из которых состоит головное понятие).

Comment: *несёт в себе понимание* — сочувствую Вашему пониманию.

Answer (score 3):

А если так:

Наука - упорядочение закономерностей.

Система, ведь, определённый порядок. Так? А наука - система знаний о закономерностях в природе, обществе и в мышлении (по Ожегову).

Comment: Слово "закономерность" подходит только к первому пункту (упорядочивание знания), ко второму пункту трудно его притянуть. Наука не занимается закономерностями в мышлении, тут Ожегов путает науку с учением, с просвещением, с воспитанием. Я не решился в своём вопросе дать побольше разделов понятия "наука", чтобы вопрос не оказался громоздким. Кому надо ссылку на расклад спрашивайте в личке.